# React Native Android Build Error MainActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my React Native android app.
The Android app can't resolve BuildConfig.DEBUG.

```
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/amirsharif/mobile-rappad/android/app/src/main/java/com/rappadmobile/MainActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainActivity
>1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

I can temporarily resolve it by simply setting it to true.
This might've happened after I changed an application name (since that's something I've also been trying to do).

I probably have to change something with Gradle so it generates the right kind of files again.

```
/**
 * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
 */
package com.app;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.rappadmobile";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I rebuilt the project with `react-native upgrade`.
My issue was then that I had old files that were referencing the old package names (because I changed the name of the app in `package.json`). Once deleting those, I resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent days trying to figure this out.

Comment: Directories with old AppName I needed to delete can be found in ./android/app/src/main/java/com   ..and ./ios

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 150):

I had the same issue and it was resolved by simply adding following import statement in `MainApplication.java`:

```
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
```

Comment: you should not do this! see this comment why: https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native/issues/269#issuecomment-437603077  The BuildConfig.java should be pulled from 
 android/app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/[your]/[package]/[name]/BuildConfig.java instead

Comment: A warning, doing this in react-native might cause the app to crash. https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/5617#issuecomment-548291420

Comment: @mvandillen my android studio has an error for 'BuildConfig', can you help, how can it auto import?

Comment: @Yogendra if you do a clean rebuild the file should be generated by React Native

Answer (score 107):

The way android knows where to find certain files, and how to connect certain files, is by using fields set in AndroidManifest.xml. Since the default setup of a React Native project, references everything with .(name-of-resource), this means that everything will be resolved with regarding to the package name set in the `<manifest>` tag. So for everything to work out of the box, and everything to be generated as expected, the path to MainActivity.java, should be the same as the package name.

Example:

Your apps package name:
`com.mycompanyname.myappname`

Location of MainActivity.java: `android/app/src/main/java/com/mycompanyname/myappname/MainActivity.java`

Comment: The package name "com.mycompany.myapp" is case sensitive.  You must also change applicationId in your /android/app/build.gradle

Comment: It was exactly my issue, thanks. I had tried to rename the app, and ended up with different names in some places. I had to ensure that the app name is similar and all lower-case in file-system folder, in app/build.gradle applicationId, in AndroidManifex.xml "package" attribute, and in package imports at MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java - the build passed after that.

Comment: This is the correct answer, over @Manoj's answer. We need not import BuildConfig manually.

Comment: if manifest package name is 'com.mycompanyname.myappname' what should be the app/build.gradle namespace and applicationId should be?

Answer (score 45):

In your `MainActivity.java`, you can check the first line is `package com.YOU_APP_NAME;`

If this line does not exist, you should add this.

Comment: I tried to change my package name and this was the last thing I forgot! Thnx!

Comment: Just for reference: I needed to change the package name in MainApplication.java as well.

Answer (score 24):

A combination of some answers helped me, summary:

- Make sure your java package names are correct (`MainApplication.java` etc.)
- update the package name in the gradle build file
- update the package name in the manifest file
- update the package name in the `BUCK` file
- make sure the path to you javascript sources is a folder structure that matches your package name

Comment: The first point "Make sure your javascript package names are correct" - are we talking the `package.json` and what do you mean by 'connect'?

Comment: This is already a while ago... but with package names I mean the first lines in the java files that are something like 'package com.yourname.yourproject'

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I changed the package name in both the BUCK file and Manifest file.

In the BUCK file, change as following.

```
android_build_config(
    name = "build_config",
    package = "NEW_PACKAGE_NAME",
)

android_resource(
    name = "res",
    package = "NEW_PACKAGE_NAME",
    res = "src/main/res", )
```

Comment: Solved my case by doing this + renaming packages in all and every Java files in my project

Answer (score 14):

If you renamed your `bundle identifier` you will likely need to change:

Your `android/app/src/main/....../MainApplication.java` **package** and **imports**.

Even though I used `react-native-rename` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename), it did not take care of some files `MainApplication.java` and `MainActivity.java`.

Answer (score 6):

Upgrading react-native solved this error:

```
react-native upgrade
```

Now build again:

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Great suggestion although it does trash some modifications to certain files. I had to run `react-native link` again after to re-link native dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the old files that might be there in **android/app/src/main/java/com**
Just keep the file with the new name of the app. Then do `react-native upgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

My case was that I renamed the package in one place(AndroidManifest.xml)
Ex:
The original: **com.example**
Changed it to: **com.example.app**

Renaming it again solved the problem

Comment: This is the solution. Do the change on `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have updated your package name in all files but failed to change the name of folder which we will same as your package name.

> android < src < main < java < com < "middlen_package_name" <
> "last_package_name".

ex: com.yourapp.gameapp;

Run the app again but if it still shows this error then ,

check if there is a folder with old package name. Delete this and rebuild again.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this while following https://dev.to/karanpratapsingh/quick-guide-for-updating-package-name-in-react-native-3ei3. I was renaming my application from `com.company_app` to `com.mycompany.myapp`, apparently, there were some files that I still needed to update but was not included in the guide I was following, I think the guide is only for general, like a fresh react-native app, I solved this by doing a global search for `com.company_app` and just replacing each one to `com.mycompany.myapp` whenever it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working with Expo and I ran to this kind of problem. Mine worked when I navigated to `android > app > build.gradle` and changed the namespace value from `com.company_app` to `com.mycompany.myapp`

Answer (score 0):

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> /media/infiniti/data/React-Native/Blog/BlogApp/android/app/src/main/java/com/anonymous/BlogApp/MainApplication.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
> return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
> **Note: alot of errors after BuildConfig.**
> after alot of time i found slon
> soln: android->app->**build.gradle**
> **android**{ **namespace** and **applicationId** must be same}
> which is "**packageNameOfApplication**"
> like **com.abcd.YourProjectName**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by making package name same as AndroidManifest.xml on these files;

> MainApplication.java, MainActivity.java located in
> "android/app/src/main/java/com/yourProjectName/"

if you do not have the package simply add

```
package com.yourAppName;
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by following these steps:
Android Version:
From Terminal go to android folder and run this command:
gradlew clean

From main project folder delete this folder:
node_modules

From menu file:
Invalidate caches and restart IDE

Find your MainActivity.java file and add this import line:
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;

In terminal, go to android folder and run this:
gradlew

in terminal, go to main root and run this:
yarn install

Now you can start the metro and run the app.

P.S.: Make sure that into the MainActivity.java file the bundleID name is correct. You will find it into the first row. Then, make sure that the MainActivity.java file is located into the correct path like this:
project_name/Android/App/src/main/java/1/2/3/MainActivity.java where 1/2/3 must be the name of your bundleID, for example, com/bundle/id

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have missed installing the react-native-gesture-handler.

## with yarn

yarn add react-native-gesture-handler

## or with npm

npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler

## Then

react-native link react-native-gesture-handler