# React native android error: cannot find symbol

Tags: android, react-native

I was trying to build an open source react native project example:

https://github.com/wix/react-native-wordpress-editor/tree/master/example

But i ran into this error after running
./react-native run-android

```
D:\e\example\node_modules\react-native-navigation\android\app\src\main\java\com\reactnativenavigation\NavigationApplica
ion.java:7: Error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                          ^
```

Anyone has any idea of whats going on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995079/react-native-android-build-error-mainactivity-java29-error-cannot-find-symbol

Comment: Having the same issue..how did you solve it?

Comment: Go to their github. I sent an issue where I answered myself. In there, i specified the detailed steps that are required for run-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should follow the third replay to this issue. Basically that helps in setting the rich editor up.

https://github.com/wix/react-native-wordpress-editor/issues/6