# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I'm new in Android Studio, I've tried to write to fire base and when android offered me something I accepted and then everything stop working and he didn't recognize any object.

I get this error:

```
**Error: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.**
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1.
```

I've already updated ths SDK and I think my dependencies are fine.
Any other suggestion?

**edit**:
i find out that it happen after i copied code from somewhere and click on "alt + enter" and then accidentally click on some option whit "...api..." (i can't restore that).

I copy the code to other computer and now it's working.

Dependencies:
[image: dependencies]

Comment: post your build.gradle file details

Comment: [could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAPKCopy'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38090248/6521116)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing your dependencies and rebuilding the app again. Try Clean and rebuild.

Comment: tried but now luck. still i am getting the same error.

Comment: You can try(in bash) : cd android && ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 4):

I got the same problem.

```
react-native upgrade
```

Find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995870/5834287 -
and it start works!

Comment: This solution actual worked for me. I spent whole day for the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing it fixed my problem. So simply remove "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.6'" from your project. Build. And run. Should be fine then

Answer (score -1):

Remove node_module and run `npm install`