# Execution failed for task & Could not delete path

Tags: android, react-native

I have `react-native` based app and every time I run it via famous `react-native run-android`. Most of the times it works, but almost every day I get this error when running, and the only thing I can do to fix it, is to pull the whole project again in the different directive. Aka. start all over.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\John\Documents\React-projects\insta-clone3\mobile\android\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\aurelhubert'.
```

Always the same exeception, `Could not delete path`. This is my `build.gradle`

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.instagramclone"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

None of the solutions I found online does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Have you tried doing `clean` after this error?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Any concrete line of code to execute? @Artyom

Comment: `gradlew clean` command from Android project root (`C:\Users\John\Documents\React-projects\insta-clone3\mobile\android` in your case)

Comment: I have got `symbol:   variable BuildConfig` after doing that. Again some error  @Artyom

Comment: Error after `react-native run-android` or while `clean`?

Comment: After `react-native run-android `

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995870

Comment: This is the reason why it crashed `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried deleting the *android/app/build* folder before running *react-native run-android* ?  In the error message you can see that something fails in *android/app/build/generated/...*

Comment: I'm sure there is another way besides deleting the whole `build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands in root directory

`cd android`

`./gradlew clean`

Then go back to root and try again

`cd ..`

`react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

First enter these commands:

```
cd android
./gradlew.bat installDebug
```

After that,

```
cd..
react-native run-android
```

It works fine for me.